# Is it possible to add a git submodule with recursive flag?

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules

I am adding a submodule to my project which contains another git repo.

To get the module I ran:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/biakaveron/debug-toolbar.git modules/debug-toolbar
```

Then ran:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Which generated this error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: ../../../../../../..//d/websites/project/.git/modules/modules/debug-toolbar/modules/vendor/firephp
Failed to recurse into submodule path 'modules/debug-toolbar'
```

I have run into similar problems before. Previously I just added the submodule and then re-cloned the project with the recursive flag (`git clone --recursive project.git`) which works. However it would be easier if I could get the submodule to pull in recursively in the first place. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you get error when not using `--recursive`? what is git version?

Comment: Using git 1.7.10. No error when not using `--recursive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause could be the fact that [github.com/cadorn/firephp-libs](https://github.com/cadorn/firephp-libs) mentions:

> THIS PROJECT HAS MOVED TO THE FOLLOWING REPOSITORIES:

```
https://github.com/firephp/firephp
https://github.com/firephp/firephp-core
```

So you might want to update the `.gitmodules` file of `debug-toolbar` first (after a `git submodule update --init`, without the `--recursive` part), and *then*, try again the `git submodule update --init --recursive`)

The OP did:

> committing, then a recursive clone - which worked.

---

Original answer:

It seems that the path definition for one of the submodules (in the [`.gitmodules` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules.html)) is not correct:
Being a *relative* path, it won't resolve successfully when cloned/updated by a `git submodule --recursive` command done from a parent repo for which said relative path is invalid.

Comment: Hi I tried `update --init` first followed by `update --recursive` but that didn't work either. I resorted back to committing, then a recursive clone - which worked.

Comment: @xylar but you did modify the `.gitmodule` to reference the new url for the `firephp` project, right? I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: ah, I forgot that step! I have already made the changes now but I will mark your answer as correct.